# Get Data from Mysql on init

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, init

I need to get data (image_url, names, etc) from mysql when the page is open.
I'm thinking to do this on oninit() event. However I'm not sure if this is the best approach.

The code I got so far is taking more time than I was expecting so maybe I'll need to add a "loading" message while this operation is going. Am I in the right way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post up some code (snippets) what you're doing right now?

Comment: Hi Harti. I can add the code later (I don't have right now). What I'm doing is: I call a php file from my html. In that file I have my query and returns the data from the database. However there is lots of information that I need to get.. Lets say about 20 items and for each item 4 items.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do, but if you use AJAX then the page load time shouldn't be affected. That's of course assuming you even need to use JavaScript—if you only need to load the data once then it's probably best to just get the data with PHP directly.

Comment: Do you need to regularly pull data from your server or just on page load?

Comment: Ynhockey actually I need the javascript. However I think my load time is beeing affected. Probably I'm not doing some thing properly...

Comment: Jamie I can do both... But if the access to the mysql takes long I'll prefer to get all on page load and then access it if I need to.

Comment: I'm thinking along the lines of what @Jamie is asking. If you don't need to ask for information/data after the page is loaded, there's no need to go into JS for this. It should be part of your page (PHP, I'm guessing). The slowness could be a number of factors: bad query, bad indexes, slow host... is it the images that take a long time to "appear"? (Check the Net monitor in Firebug or other dev tools)  Is it the query itself that takes a long time? (try a timer that starts right before the query and ends right after)

Comment: isotrope I don't need to ask for that information but I need that information in js. I have several items and each item has several pictures. I need to know how much items and how much images per item... So I guess I'll need to go with JS? The query is pretty simple... I just select the items table and I'm "left joinning" with images table. I got this idea that is slow because when I access this data after an event (lets say onclick) and then do an "alert" of the result of ther query this is empty. Just when I click again this is not empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, there are scenarios here -- and I'm not too sure about what you need.  The first is pulling the data **once** on page load.  You present your data through a view using a controller to access your data model. Everything is processed on page load and is static.

```
// Use simple PHP

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","peter","abc123");
if(!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['image'];
    echo $row['names'];
    // etc.
}
?>
```

The second is more dynamic, using AJAX to pull data from your server continuously.  You can use JavaScript's setInterval to load data over a regular period:

```
// Load MySQL data every 15 seconds with jQuery

$(function () {
   setInterval(function() {
      $.ajax({
         url: '/path/to/controller',
         data: 'var1=hey&var2=bro',
         dataType: 'html',
         type: 'POST',
         success: function(data) {
           $('.div_of_your_choice').html(data);
         })
      });
   },15000);
});
```

Comment: Jamie thanks! Actually I just need to pull the data once but I'll access it later. Should I do it oninit event?   Another thing... I'm pulling about 10 columns and 50 rows lets say.. how can I store this data and access it later? I was thinking in create an Array of Arrays for that.. Do you think there's another (faster) way? thanks again. .Regards

Comment: You don't need to initialize an AJAX call if you're using PHP. Call MySQL using PHP so that the server loads everything rather than making your visitors wait unnecessarily.

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial for more information: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: Yes Jamie. That makes sense and thanks for the link. However I couldn't figure it out how can I "store" the information and access it later. Do you have any idea? I'm thinking about the array ou array as I mentioned before or a "hidden table" but just the name sounds weird...